# FormControl ValueChanges event not firing when setValue is called

Tags: angular

I have the following code for an Angular 4 type-ahead component:
There is a FormControl in the FormGroup which is tied with the html and it works perfectly.

```
this.ProfileForm.controls["code"]
```

The valueChanges event is firing when i change in the textbox. Now when i update the formcontrol value through programatically the valueChanges event is not firing.
The following is the lines of code i written.

```
this.ProfileForm.controls["code"].setValue("someValue");

this.ProfileForm.controls["code"].valueChanges.subscribe(() => {
            console.log("modified");}, () => { console.log("error") }, () => { console.log("completed") });
```

Any suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure that you are not reinitialise form?

Comment: Yes, i am not reinitialising.

Comment: can you please post full sourcecode? not just parts from different places

Comment: Btw in code you have setValue before subscribe?

Comment: Yes, it is positioned correctly in the code.

Comment: Could you create a plunker that showcases this issue?

Comment: I couldn't create a plunker as it is huge code. I can only provide the above small  code. Another point i can say is both the statements valueChanges and setValue are in different methods. ngOnInit() contains the valueChanges() method and some button click has the setValue() method.

Answer (score 11):

Change it to subscribe first and then setValue

```
this.ProfileForm.controls["code"].valueChanges.subscribe(() => {
            console.log("modified");}, () => { console.log("error") }, () => { console.log("completed") });

this.ProfileForm.controls["code"].setValue("someValue");
```

Because in your code you are changing value while you are not yet subscribed.

Comment: As in the comment, the position of codes are correct position as you mentioned.

Comment: @Bhimisetty what do you mean?

Comment: My code is like this only this.ProfileForm.controls["code"].valueChanges.subscribe(() => {
            console.log("modified");}, () => { console.log("error") }, () => { console.log("completed") });

this.ProfileForm.controls["code"].setValue("someValue");

Comment: #"¤%/%#"§"! me! It's an hot observable!? Well, thanks for the help - was getting frustrated why it didn't work when it should :D

Answer (score 0):

It may be helpful.
I have similar problem because of incorrect value set.

```
this.formGroup = this._formBuilder.group({
  city: [new Location()]
});

this.cityControl = this.formGroup.get('city');

this.citiesListOptions = this.cityControl.valueChanges.pipe(
  map(name => this._filterCity(name))
);
```

when i used this:

```
this.cityControl.patchValue(null);
```

then cityControl.valueChanges not fire again.

when i correct to this, worked:

```
this.cityControl.patchValue(new Location() )
```